# How to get the custom option value in protobuf of javascript version?

Tags: javascript, protobuf.js

I used custom option for a static mapping purpose. Things are working fine in python, java, c++ code. But the custom option field is missing when generating js code.

What I did :

```
extend enumValueOption
{
     string test = 50001;
}

enum myEnum{
    ENUM1 = 0 [test = "for fun" ];
}
```

I am using proto3 and using ubuntu.